# Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 473 (line 1 column 474)

Tags: javascript, php

estoy haciendo unas practicas pero tengo un error y es que al querer interactuar con el backend me sale este error Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 473 (line 1 column 474)
lo que estoy haciendo es un cambio en la base de datos con un frontend que hace petición al backend

```
nuevoIcono.addEventListener('click', function () {
                fetch('http://localhost/Js/actualizarEstado.php?id=' + pc.id, {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        id: pc.id,
                        nuevoEstadoId: nuevoEstadoId
                    }),
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log("Respuesta del servidor:", data);
                    if (data.success) {
                        if (nuevoEstadoId === 1) {
                            nuevoIcono.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                        } else if (nuevoEstadoId === 2) {
                            nuevoIcono.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.error("El servidor no pudo actualizar el estado.");
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                    alert("Error al actualizar el estado de la PC");
                });
            });
```

en el backend php en donde estoy haciendo el cambio

```
public function actualizarEstado() {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    if (isset($data['id']) && isset($data['nuevoEstadoId'])) {
        $id = $data['id'];
        $nuevoEstadoId = $data['nuevoEstadoId'];
        
        $conn = new DB();
        $sql = "UPDATE pc SET id_estado = $nuevoEstadoId WHERE id = $id";

        if ($conn->execute_query($sql)) {
            echo json_encode(array("success" => true));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array("success" => false));
            exit();
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

pero al dar click me sale ese error, si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho

Comment: seguramente tu endpoint  esta generando alguna alerta que se imprime después de la cadena en formato json, te sugiero, que des "inspeccionar", luego en "Network" o "Red" dependiendo del idioma, después des clic sobre el botón que envía el request al servidor (que en tu caso seria nuevoIcono), cuando hagas eso podrás ver que se visualiza una nueva petición, das clic sobre esta y luego en Response, ahí veras el resultado de la solicitud.